# Dragging Cells and Updating

Tags: excel

Suppose we have two sheets `Sheet 1` and `Sheet 2`. The numbers in `Sheet 2` call the numbers from `Sheet 1`. Suppose I have numbers in every two columns in `Sheet 1`. How would I update `Sheet 2`?

For example, suppose in the first row of  `Sheet 1` we have the numbers 1 to 10 in `A1, C1, E1, ...`

In `Sheet 2` I write `='Sheet1'!A1`, but when I drag this over it only updates the letter to the next letter. I want it to update every two letters.

```
  Input: Numbers 1-10  on cells A1, C1, E1, ...S1 on Sheet1
  Output: Numbers 1-10 on cells A1, B1, C1, ..., J1 on Sheet2
```

Comment: Give us example input and desired output. Question is not clear.

Comment: @pnuts: that takes too long

Answer (score 0):

perhaps

```
=INDEX'Sheet1'!1:1,,(column()-1)*2+1)
```